# Problem with @Configuration annotation. Singelton bean created too early

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar, axon

I am fairly new to this type of programming. In fact this is my first Java project with this Spring setting. For my web app which delivers good results locally on Postman and a h2 console, i have created a jarfile. Now, executing this jar file, among other problematic messages the console gripes:

```
Cannot enhance @Configuration bean definition 
        'org.axonframework.springboot.autoconfig.EventProcessingAutoConfiguration' 
         since its
        singleton instance has been created too early. The typical cause is a non- 
        static @Bean method with a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor return 
        type: 
        Consider declaring such methods as 'static'.
```

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebsocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config){
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        //config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws")
                .setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }
    }
```

The only Class i used this annotation is my web socket Config class above.
 But i don't see how "static" solves this problem, much less understand.
I have already looked all over the internet for this specific problem and have watched tutorials on spring bean definitions. Still i am not sure i can pin down the issue here. If You need some more Code from my classes let me know.

Comment: https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot/issues/45

This should help you

Comment: thanks, So if i get it right, there is no issue?

Comment: I guess there shouldn't be any

Comment: It looks like it may be a problem with Axon's Spring Boot auto-configuration rather than anything in your own code. Which version of Axon are you using?

Comment: 'org.axonframework:axon-spring-boot-starter:4.0.3' is the version i am working with.